# Google PlaceAutoCompleteFragment inside fragment not working

Tags: android-fragments

I used Google Places AutocompleteFragment for loading address from user. The selected address from the dropdown list working fine inside Activity. But when i use fragment instead of Activity, its not working.

Comment: You need to be more clear with your query! What was working with activity but not with fragment? You mean with the activity you were able to receive the onPlaceSelected callback? Also add more helpful tags to your question like "google-places-api","mapfragment" etc to attract more attention.

Comment: I am able to get address from activity, but when i use fragment autocomplete callback not working

Comment: Pls share the code depicting how you are using PlaceAutocompleteFragment inside your fragment (including the xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Google Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#option_1_embed_a_placeautocompletefragment_or_a_supportplaceautocompletefragment), if your fragment is nested within another fragment, your app must also forward onActivityResult() calls from the containing fragment to work around a known limitation of android.support.v4.app.Fragment. This is shown in the following snippet:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    autocompleteFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this approach but it appears that onActivityResult is not being called. Logcat shows "E/Places: Unknown PlaceAutocompleteAdapter state change."

Comment: Callbacks were not working because my PlaceSelectedListener was not initialized due to incorrect retrieval of my fragment (fragment was null). mAutocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment); was the correct way to retrieve the fragment in my case.